# og:image not showing

Tags: facebook, image

A few hours ago every og tag was working properly, showing correct og:images and so (even though the images were small). I didn't change nothing in the tags or images size, but now when I share an url on facebook it doesn't show the og:image

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="my title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="my description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="my image url"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My web name" />
```

Its important that yesterday everything was ok even though the image sizes and now without change nothing it doesn't work.

-Edited: On Google+ everything is ok with the og:image.

Comment: What does [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) say?

Comment: First, sorry for my english Igy. Well, it says image too small... but I already said that I never changed nothing on my code or in the images size and before today it just worked perfectly.

Comment: Is the debug tool correctly detecting the real size of the image? is the error message in the debug tool correct?

Comment: can I post the url to see yourself in the debug tool and/or FB page?

Comment: Look at the url yourself in the debug tool - if it says the image is too small, check if the image is ACTUALLY too small - if it is, use a bigger image, if it isn't, file a bug report with facebook

Comment: Igy I already said that before the image already was small but just worked perfectly and now... without change nothing, just not showing on facebook. Ok, lets see, the problem its the image size ¿right? then, why before always showed on FB and now not? ... and I can't or I don't know how to report bugs, only can read other bugs, but not report.

Comment: ok, I see that the fact "even though before already was small, and I didn't change nothing, now it doesn't show" it doesn't matter or its invisible...

Comment: Lo pondré en español para explicarme mejor y por si alguien habla mi idioma.

Se que Facebook recomienda tener un mínimo de 200x200 en las dimensiones de las imágenes que se incluyan en el tag "og:image". En todas las páginas de mi web las imágenes son más pequeñas que 200x200 pero SIEMPRE se mostraron correctamente.

El problema es que ahora ha dejado de mostrarse correctamente la imagen indicada en "og:image". Y lo que no entiendo es por qué antes se me mostraba correctamente a pesar del tamaño pequeño y ahora ya no.

Comment: ni caso... y esto sigue sin funcionar...

Comment: more people with the same problem and no one gives a solution...

Comment: I put an image bigger than 200x200 and now the problem is that debugger doesn't show any error but when I post on Facebook, instead of the og:image, it shows three images........ the image size doesn't work... then what we have to do?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when using mod_pagespeed with apache, facebook linter said image was too small but it wasn't, afyer disabling mod_pagespeed it now shows perfect on the debugger with no errors but it still doesn't show on facebook, but I guess there's nothing I can do if it works perfectly on the debugger, maybe wait.

If you have recently installed mod_pagespeed on your server it might help disabling it.